# Constructing a circle that internally tangents a circle $\gamma$ and passes through two internal points.

Tags: geometry

The full details of this problem is given as follows

> Construct a circle $\gamma$ with center $O_\gamma$ ,  and 
>     place two points $A$ and $B$ inside $\gamma$. That does not lie on the edge of the circle. Explain the construction of a point $C$, such that the circle $ABC =\beta$, is internally tangential to $\gamma$.

Now $ABC$ means a circle that passes through the points $A$,$B$ and $C$. I have made a drawing, but I am unable to mathematicaly construct the point $C$. 
I already know that for most pairs $A$,$B$ there are two possible choices for $C$. Eg $C_1$ and $C_2$. See the following figure

[image: Drawing]

Can anyone show me or help me in finding the placement of $C$, given $A$ and $B$?
The figure is only but a sketch, but I know that the centre of the circle obviously has to lie on the perpendicular bisector of A and B, after that I am clueless.

Comment: I'd say that the tangent in C is perpendicular to both $O_\beta$ and $O_\gamma$?

Comment: So $C$, $O_\gamma$ and $O_\beta$ are collinear?

Comment: i think the answer might be on  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32386/finding-the-circles-passing-through-two-points-and-touching-a-circle?rq=1  (last part of accepted answer)

Comment: You're looking for a circle that is tangent to two given circles?

Comment: Given two points A and B inside a circle $\gamma$. 
Find a point $C$ that lies on $\gamma$, such that the circle that passes through $A$,$B$,$C$ only touches $\gamma$ at $C$.

http://folk.ntnu.no/oistes/Diverse/sirkelmaple.pdf

Comment: "for most pairs $A,B$ there are two possible choices for $C$": for _all_ pairs, surely?

Answer (score 2):

I gave an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/625571/21820), which applies to the general case of finding a circle tangent to three circles, which may have up to 8 solutions. This particular case is a degenerate one where two of the circles are points, and has only 2 solutions. It can be solved by the last step of the general solution I gave, which is to invert at one of the two points, and the desired circle will become a line that must be tangent to a circle and pass through a point, which is easy to construct. Inversion can be easily constructed using compass and straightedge also, and the original desired solutions can likewise be obtained by undoing the inversion.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the general solution of the apollonius PPC which works fine for this case:

draw any circle $\Gamma$ that passes through $A$ and $B$ and meets $\gamma$ in two points $M$ and $N$.
Let $H = MN \cap AB$ draw the tangents from $H$ to $\gamma$ and let $T$ and $S$ be the contact points of these tangent lines.
The circles you want are the circles $\odot (TAB)$ and $\odot (SAB)$.
The construction works because $H$ is by construction the radical center of $\gamma$, $\Gamma$ and the solutions and therefore lies in the common tangent line of the solutions and $\gamma$.