# (geometry) How to construct inscribed circle between 3 circles?

Tags: geometry, circles

Suppose I have 3 circles not overlapping (but possibly touching) each other. Is there always an inscribed circle that is touching (i.e. tangent to) each of the 3 circles? And if yes, how do I construct it?

For example if I have 3 circles like this:

[image: circles]

I would like to construct approximately this inscribed circle:

[image: inscribed circle]

Comment: Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius

Comment: Geogebra is excellent for this, gives an exact construction. Denote A,B,C the centers of the circles. The center of the fourth circle lies on hyperbolas 1) with foci A,B 2) with foci B,C 3) with foci A,C. It suffices to construct two of them. You will also need one point of each hyperbola. For, construct the line segment AB. It cuts the corresponding circles at points, say P and Q. The hyperbola passes through the midpoint of PQ. For a proof, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2967187/generate-a-circle-centered-on-a-line-and-touching-2-other-circles/2968098?r=SearchResults#2968098

Comment: Thanks, awesome  This is not a construction I can do with compass and ruler, right?

Comment: you can construct the circle with compass and straight edge alone. just shrink the smallest circle into a point and you get 2 circles and a point then the construction is easy  =https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/PCC.shtml&ved=2ahUKEwi7r-S-t5zrAhWNcn0KHa0bARIQFjAAegQIAhAC&usg=AOvVaw3WO6bP5xoHSGyxztwCCUIS&cshid=1597467875781

Comment: @RockeNuts answer to your first question: yes, it is possible. This is one of the family of Apollonius problems. As for a construction, the question  has already an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861627/circle-tangent-to-three-circles  For your question in the comment: if a construction with conic sections exists, then a construction with ruler and compass is possible.

Comment: @RocketNuts, if the comments answer your question, could you write up an answer?

Comment: @endgameendgame Thanks, yes I see how shrinking the circles until the smallest one becomes a point, reduces the problem to two circles and a point. I now also see how this can be solved with hyperbolas, however I don't see how this is possible with just a compass and ruler. The link you included seems to contain only a front or cover page, not sure where to go from there, was it supposed to contain an explanation?

Comment: sorry it my mistake... here is the link https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/PCC.shtml&ved=2ahUKEwj55aLE_J7rAhXO4HMBHRcLBLwQFjAAegQIARAC&usg=AOvVaw3WO6bP5xoHSGyxztwCCUIS&cshid=1597555152774

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861627/circle-tangent-to-three-circles/4828348#4828348

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Cut The Knot](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/) website has a good [overview](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Apollonius.shtml) of this construction, which is known as the Problem of Apollonius.  It can be broken down into several versions, where finding a circle tangent to three circles is the most general.  Less general versions, such as for three tangent circles, or [two circles and a point](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/PCC.shtml) have shorter constructions.  An even more general version, perhaps, is constructing a circle that has a given angle with the given circles.

One possible construction is [Gergonne's Solution](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/CCC_Gergonne.shtml). This involves sub constructions which are listed at the bottom of the overview page.

The comments to your question also point to other discussions, such as [circle tangent to three circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861627/circle-tangent-to-three-circles) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius).